# Flutter http package

Tags: android, ios, flutter, http

I am using latest version of Flutter SDK 3.10.6 and http package version is 1.1.0, When users with Honor FNE-NX9 android 13 api 33 downloading my application from Play Store all APIs response is null but in debug mode on the same device there is no problem.

Is there any way to fix it?

this permission is already i added in manifest and i already added android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
these parameters to application tag in manifest

Comment: for my case , i often forget to add internet permission on main/AndroidManifest

Comment: decompile release apk/aab check your response data bean whether to been proguarded